# Spring/Hibernate/JPA: Prevent reassigning child to another parent

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working in a SpringBoot application with Hibernate that exposes a REST interface.

**The Problem**

Users are able to create objects, let's name them `parent`. Users can associate the `parent` object with several `child` items. These items are also composed of other objects, but lets keep it simple for now. I want to prevent the case that a client can do the following:

- create `parent1` and create `child1, child2`
- create `parent2` and create `child3`
- update `parent1` with `child3` in payload

This behaviour should not be possible as the `child` items should not be updatable when they belong to another parent. 
My goal is to make it impossible to update `parent` and update any `child` that belongs to a different `parent`.

**The model**

```
@Entity(name = "Parent")
@Table(name = "t_parent")
data class Parent(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent")
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val children: MutableList<Child> = mutableListOf()
)

@Table(name = "t_child")
@Entity(name = "Child")
data class Child(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int = 0,
)
```

I am using Spring's `JpaRepository` for persistence.

**Solutions?**

The 'dumbest' way of doing this would be to fetch `parent1` from the database and remove all `child` items from the client's request that are not contained in `dbParent1`. This is quite tedious and not really smart I guess.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

What about transactions? In a transactional method you can check if a child belongs to another parent. If you find any obstacle for update/insert or whatever, then rollback the transaction (for example, just throw an exception). This methodology will require additional service layer in your archtecture since the code of repos is autogenerated from interface declarations. 
This approach is described here: [How to override save method of CrudRepository REST wise](https://outofrange.ru/2016/11/how-to-override-save-method-of-crudrepository-rest-wise/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the following way for the update operation:

1) Fetch the parent with `childId`

2a) If there are no parents, then just add the child to the parent (new child)

2b) Otherwise, check if the child belongs to the parent (you can use parentId probably set in the `@PathVariable`

2b1) If not, throw a `new IllegalArgumentException("wrong parent")`

2b2) Otherwise, update parent